# Spark 1.4 image for Google Cloud?

Tags: apache-spark, google-hadoop, apache-spark-1.4

With bdutil, the latest version of tarball I can find is on spark 1.3.1:

gs://spark-dist/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz

There are a few new DataFrame features in Spark 1.4 that I want to use. Any chance the Spark 1.4 image be available for bdutil, or any workaround?

UPDATE:

Following the suggestion from Angus Davis, I downloaded and pointed to spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz, the deployment went well; however, run into error when calling SqlContext.parquetFile(). I cannot explain why this exception is possible, GoogleHadoopFileSystem should be a subclass of org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem. Will continue investigate on this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2595)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getFs(Warehouse.java:112)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDnsPath(Warehouse.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getWhRoot(Warehouse.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDefaultDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:177)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:504)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
```

Asked a separate question about the exception [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478955/googlehadoopfilesystem-cannot-be-cast-to-hadoop-filesystem)

UPDATE:

The error turned out to be a Spark defect; resolution/workaround provided in the above question.

Thanks!

Haiying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a local workaround is acceptable, you can copy the spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz from an apache mirror into a bucket that you control. You can then edit extensions/spark/spark-env.sh and change SPARK_HADOOP2_TARBALL_URI='<your copy of spark 1.4.1>' (make certain that the service account running your VMs has permission to read the tarball).

Note that I haven't done *any* testing to see if Spark 1.4.1 works out of the box right now, but I'd be interested in hearing your experience if you decide to give it a go.